# jQuery - Redactor

Tags: php

I am trying to initiate some sort of beginning of an admin panel, so if an IP is equal to an allowed IP, it will show an edit button. I currently have my localhost and my server's IP just for test purposes. But once I set more then one IP to $allowed, it doesn't work.

Heres the code:

```
<?PHP
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = '127.0.0.1, 67.202.102.224';
?>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
<?PHP
if ($ip == $allowed){
echo '<p>
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToEdit();">Edit</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToSave();">Save</button>   
</p>';
}
?>
```

Comment: The title of this question is totally undescriptive of the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<?php
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$allowed = array('127.0.0.1',
                 '::1',
                 '67.202.102.224',
                 );
?>

<!--dont forget the rest of your head-->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="page">
<?php
if (in_array($ip, $allowed)){
    echo '<p>
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToEdit();">Edit</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="exampleClickToSave();">Save</button>   
</p>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $ip won't ever equal $allowed. You could check if the $ip is present in the $allowed string:

```
if (strpos($allowed, $ip) !== FALSE) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a php expert, but it seems like you're trying to compare $ip to a long string `127.0.0.1, 67.202.102.224` which will always be false.  You need to separate your IPs like this `"127.0.0.1", "67.202.102.224"`

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing strings. There is no way that the string `'67.202.102.224'` is going to be equal to `'127.0.0.1, 67.202.102.224'`.

I don't know any PHP, but with some Googling I found the following code you could use:

```
$allowed = array('127.0.0.1', '67.202.102.224');
if (in_array($ip, $allowed)) { ...
```